# Passing variables to a jquery callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem passing a variable through into a jquery function:

```
function showImage(type, top, url) {
$.getJSON('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>',{
    type: type,
    top: top,
    img: url,
    action: 'imginfo'    
    }, function(retval) {
        if (retval['isimg']) {
            $('#tdDimensions').html(retval['dimension']);
            $('#thPreview').html(retval['previewtext']);
            alert($('#tdPreview').html());
            alert(img);
```

This is part of my code, but the problem is that in the success function (`function(retval)`) I cannot acces the parameters passed to `showImage()` anymore.

How can I realise this so that the `alert(img)` in this code will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I realise this so that the alert(img) in this code will work?

Just use `url` arg from `showImage` - your callback, as inner function, has access to it. Read more about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) if you're not sure why.

Comment: Oh damn sorry, I thought there was a problem accessing vars from within the callback, but it was just my own stupidity... sigh :) Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

`alert(url)` should do the trick in this case ;)

You can also put that anonymous object literal in a variable

```
var params = {
    type: type,
    top: top,
    img: url,
    action: 'imginfo'    
};

$.getJSON("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>", params, function(retval) { ... } );
```

so you can access any of its properties if you want to:

```
alert( params.img );
```